# Is there a way to tell from the (C#) code-behind when I insert into a Sharepoint List from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, splistitem, codebehind

I want to respond to the insertion of data into a Sharepoint list (which will be done from the client/JavaScript (*.asxc file) in the code-behind/C#.

Is there a way to do that? Can I hook up an "OnListUpdated" handler in the Sharepoint Web Part's code-behind (*.ascx.cs) file?

I want to let the user just select one button, which will populate the list (from the client) and then immediately thereafter generate a PDF file (from the server).

Comment: Why don't you insert data from server side code as well? Other way I can think of is you take a server-side button and call OnClientClick as well as OnClick.. first client-side code will be executed than server-side code will be executed

Comment: The client-side values are nearly impossible to retrieve from the server-side code. I have two viable options AFAICT: create the controls/elements in C# (kind of a pain, especially since I've already got the HTML written) OR insert the data from the client-side, which requires an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look into event handlers for this. You're probably looking for the `ItemUpdated` event.

[How to create an event receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563(v=vs.120).aspx)

Also

[MSDN ItemUpdated event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated.aspx)